# Should I use .net 2.0 or user any newer version?

Tags: .net

I have almost completed my .net app in .net 2.0 on windows 8.1
The reason for developing in 2.0 was that I wanted to run the app on windows7, 8 and 8.1 because .net 2.0 was available in all.
So my question is that should I switch to any newer version of .net or stick to 2.0?
Please tell me any reason to use newer .net framework and side effects of using 2.0
Or is there any other way to run my app on all version of windows?

Regards.

Comment: Windows 7 includes .NET 3.5.

Comment: Also, to avoid this question being closed as being primarily opinion-based, you could rephrase it as "what are the advantages and disadvantage of targeting newer or older versions of .NET" rather than "Should **I** target newer or older versions".

Answer (score 2):

The only side effect to keep using .NET 2.0 is that you will not have access to features of newer .NET, such as LINQ, Task Parallel Library, etc.

See this [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history) for a full comparison of framework features by version.

Windows 7 already comes with .NET 3.5 built in, so if that is really the earliest OS you intend to target, there is really no need to taget .NET 2.0.

If you target .NET 3.5, Windows 7 users can run it with no prerequisite to install .NET 4.0 or higher, but Windows 8 users will need to enable .NET 3.5 (see Scott Chamberlain's answer). So either way, there is a tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

If the earliest version of windows you are targeting is Windows 7 that comes with .NET 3.5 installed. However Windows 8 and 8.1 comes with .NET 4.0 installed which will not run a 3.5 app, so your end user would need to end up "installing" (actually just enabling the windows feature) of .NET 3.5 before your program will work.

All of your targeted versions of windows can run the latest versions of .NET (4.5.2 as of this writing), so I just recommend targeting that and including a installer that will install .NET for the user if it is not already installed.